# Yii jQuery get model value and submit form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii, model

In the view part **_form.php**, it has `$model` and a CActiveForm `$form`.
I wrote JavaScript to compare the `$model->publication_date` and current date,
if same, it will submit the form, if not it will has a confirm box to choose.

```
$form.on("submit",function(){
var formDate=$model->publication_date.val(); (error)
if(formDate != today){
   var windowpop= confirm("The publication_date is not today, do you want to change it to today");
   if(r==true){
        $model->publication_date= today;
        $form.submit();
   }
   else
       $form.submit();
 }
else
   $form.submit();
 });
```

but it seems has many errors like I can't get `$model` attributes in JavaScript function
How can I use like `$model` attributes and submit the CActiveForm?

Comment: `$model->publication_date` is a PHP variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$model->attributeName` is a PHP variable, and is not available to the client JavaScript/jQuery.

To get the value with jQuery, use:

```
$("input[id$='publicationDate']").val()
```

To set the value with jQuery, use:

```
$("input[id$='publicationDate']").val(today)
```

---

By the way, you also cannot access the PHP variable `$form`. You have to do a jQuery selector to get it as well:

```
var $form = $('form:first'); // change accordingly
```